# Asíncrono y síncrono con Retrofit en Android

Tags: android

Me gustaría, por favor, si alguien puede explicar lo de síncrono y asíncrono en Android. No llego a entender porque una llamada asíncrona  a un servidor usando Retrofit no puede devolver nada, es decir tiene que ser un metodo void, por ejemplo.

```
public interface GithubRepositoryService {
    @GET("/url/{owner}/{name}")
    void repository(@Path("owner") String owner, @Path("name") String name,  Callback<Repository> callback);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Asíncrono**, se refiere a que realizas la invocación de un método o tarea pero continuas con la ejecución sin esperar un resultado. Importante hacer notar que generalmente se define un "Callback" que es un método que recibirá el resultado de la respuesta.
>
> **Sincrono**, la invocación de un método o tarea se realiza, pero espera el resultado, y no continua la ejecución hasta que se obtenga
>   un resultado.

En tu ejemplo se tiene un tipo `void`, ya que estas definiendo una petición Asíncrona y quien recibe la respuesta es el Callback :

```
public interface GithubRepositoryService {
    @GET("/repos/{owner}/{name}")
    void repository(@Path("owner") String owner, @Path("name") String name,  Callback<Repository> callback);
}
```

Al definir el Callback puedes recibir tu respuesta en el método `success()` :

```
    Callback callback = new Callback {

       @Override 
       public void success(Repository repository, final Response response) { 
       //* Aquí recibes tu respuesta ! ...
       ... 
       }

       @Override 
       public void failure(final RetrofitError error) { ... }

       }

    service.repository(owner, name, callback);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Elenasys